# Why does the donate button displays space above it?

Tags: html

I am using the following donate button on a [website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/?page_id=3377) and it seems to take a lot of space. Please tell me why is this happening.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="bla@bla.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `a lot of space` ?? can you prefer a screenshot of the same?? My understanding:  When i inspected it was `dispaly:block` remove it to prevent its existence for the full width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place code in WordPress text editor, it takes a new line as a 
.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="bla@bla.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Becomes,

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="bla@bla.com">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<br>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<br>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
<br>
</form>
```

To avoid this, remove all the new lines from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try inputting this instead:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="bla@bla.com"><input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation"><input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721"><input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"><input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the numerous `<br>` tags

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="nayajeevan@njfk.org">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Naya Jeevan Foundation">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="26-0551721">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <br>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/?page_id=3377

I checked your url and find that u you have put 'br' tag after all input hiddens. 
Remove that 'br' tags. Donate button will automatically appear on top.